# Date format issue with HIbernate, spring, informix

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting a DateTime field from informix Database using hibernate and need to reformat my date as 2016-11-24 12:45:41

> I am getting date as  "updateTime":
>   **"2012-08-31T12:19:50.000+0000"**.

```
update_time DATETIME

Hibernate code
   @Column(name = "update_time")
    private Timestamp updateTime;
```

Comment: Hey! Please add more information. *FYI:* Persisting and formatting is not the same thing.

Comment: Are you saying you need to format it when it comes out of the database?  Or are you saying you're getting some kind of error.  Your question is kind of unclear.

Comment: I need to reformat it when it comes out of Database. Current format for updateTime when it is fetched from DB is "2012-08-31T12:19:50.000+0000" But I need to reformat it to 2016-11-24 12:45:41 before I send it to Rest client.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a Bean class in your Application:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateTimeSerializer;

@Configuration
public class ContactAppConfig {

    private static final String dateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
        return builder -> {
            builder.simpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat);
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat)));
        };
    }
}
```